# WiX installation - move installed files to another drive

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer

I've tried multiple things and I cannot figure out the proper way to do this.  I have a folder that I install along with my application that contains some files used by an instrument.  I install the application to the C:\ drive, but I need these few files to be placed on the D:\ drive.  What is the proper way to move files to another drive in WiX?

Our solution in the past was a .bat file that moves them, but I also cannot figure out the proper way to run a batch file in WiX.  Either moving the files via WiX, or calling a batch file would solve my problem.  Help on either would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define Property with the Drive D:

```
<SetDirectory Id="DDrive" Value="D:\AppName" Sequence="both"/>
```

Set the directory:

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
    <Directory Id="DDrive" Name="AppName">
        <Directory Id="Folder" Name="Folder"/>
    </Directory>
</Directory>
```

And now you can declare your Components using the directory DDrive.

Comment: how can I move a certain folder only?